# Tela de Login não valida

Tags: php

Tenho uma página em HTML simples, que contem apenas um Login e senha;

```
<form id="geral"  action="valida.php" method="POST" accept-charset="iso-8859-1">

            <h3><img border="0" src="financeiro/img/logo/1.png" width="80" height="70"> </h3>

            <div class="form-group-login">
                <label for="login">  </label>
                                     <input  name="login" id="login" type="text" placeholder="Digite o seu login..." />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group-login">
                <label for="password">  </label>
                    <input name="password" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Digite sua senha..." />
                         <!--<button id="btn_login" class="botao">Entrar</button> -->
                          <button  type="submit" id="enviar" value="enviar" class="botao" >Entrar</button>




        </form>
```

Após digitar Login e senha, é direcionado a um arquivo chamado valida.php. Neste arquivo, apenas consulta outro arquivo chamado seguranca.php, cujo arquivo faz toda análise de segurança para logar o usuário ou não.

valida.php

```
valida.php

    //Inclui o arquivo com o sistema de segurança
require_once("seguranca.php");

//Verifica se um formulário foi enviado
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    //Salva duas variáveis com o que foi digitado no formulário
    //Detalhe: faz uma verificação com isset() pra saber se o campo foi preenchido
    $usuario = (isset($_POST['login'])) ? $_POST['login'] : '';
    $senha = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

    //Utiliza uma função criada no seguranca.php para validar os dados digitados
    if (validaUsuario($usuario, $senha) == true) {
        // O usuário e a senha digitados foram validados, manda pra pagina interna
        header("Location: /financeiro/index.html");
    }else {
     // O usuário e/ou a senha são inválidos, manda de volta pro form de login
     // Para alterar o endereço da pagina de login, verifique o arquivo 





    expulsaVisitante();
        }
    }
```

seguranca.php

```
Seguranca.php

    function validaUsuario($usuario, $senha) {
global $_SG;
//$cS = ($_SG['caseSensitive']) ? 'BINARY' : '';
// Usa a função addslashes para escapar as aspas
//$nusuario = addslashes($usuario);
//$nsenha = addslashes($senha);
//$senhamd5 = md5($nsenha);
// Monta uma consulta SQL (query) para procurar um usuário

$sql = "SELECT `id`, `nome` FROM usuario` WHERE  `usuario` = '$usuario' AND `senha` = '$senha' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

// Verifica se encontrou algum registro
if ($resultado) {


// Definimos dois valores na sessão com os dados do usuário
$_SESSION['usuarioID'] = $resultado['id']; // Pega o valor da coluna 'id do registro encontrado no MySQL
$_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome']; // Pega o valor da coluna 'nome' do registro encontrado no MySQL

// Verifica a opção se sempre validar o login
if ($_SG['validaSempre'] == true) {

// Definimos dois valores na sessão com os dados do login
$_SESSION['usuarioLogin'] = $usuario;
$_SESSION['usuarioSenha'] = $senha;
}
return true;


// Nenhum registro foi encontrado => o usuário é inválido


} else {

 return false;

  }
}
```

O problema é que colocando dados certos ou errados ele não deixa logar. Ele cai sempre no Returne false, do IF na função validaUsuario. Se testar colocando if (isset($resultado)), ele deixa logar com dados certos ou errados.

Debugando o código, dei um echo nas variaveis e o erro é este:

```
 Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\web\web\seguranca.php on line 55
SELECT id, nome FROM usuario WHERE usuario = 'teste' AND senha = '123mudar' LIMIT 1
```

Se eu jogo este select diretamente via terminal me tras a coluna com estes dados, porem pesquisando diz que o erro é na Query.

Comment: se você der um echo em $usuario e $senha antes da query select, oque retorna?, está vindo os dados?

Comment: Fiz um teste, comentando a linha que cai na função de Expulsausuario e coloquei um echo conforme me pediu e de fato não está pegando nada.

Comment: amigo você está esquecendo de iniciar a session faça session_start(); @user54154

Comment: No arquivo seguranca.php, no começo do códido eu tenho session_start();, é que não coloquei este trecho aqui.

Comment: inicia a session ali dentro do arquivo que valida

Comment: Coloquei o session_start(); no inicio do valida.php e tb não pega as variaveis.

Comment: Tira todos os ` da query. Quando vc chama um campo da tabela não precisa colocar isso.

Comment: Tb não precisa desse `LIMIT 1`, já que vc quer apenas saber se o registro em questão "existe" ou "não".

Comment: Já tinha feito este teste de remover o LIMIT e os  `, porem mesmo erro mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primeira coisa importantíssima que você tem que levar em consideração é que todas as funções (mysql_* e mysqli_*) estão obsoletas e a partir da versão 7 do php já foram removidas.

A segunda coisa é quando você for trabalhar com qualquer tipo de parâmetro sendo passado dentro do sql, nunca se deve colocar as variáveis dentro de aspas simples '', ex. **"select * from table where id='$id'"**, isto gera um problema pois o php irá interpretar sua variável como uma string, para evitar isso sua instrução deve ficar da seguinte forma: **"select * from table where id={$id}"** ou **"select * from table where id=$id"**.

Como deveria ficar sua consulta:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `nome` FROM usuario` WHERE  `usuario` = {$usuario} AND `senha` = {$senha} LIMIT 1";
```

ou...

```
 $sql = "SELECT `id`, `nome` FROM usuario` WHERE  `usuario` = ".$usuario." AND `senha` = ".$senha." LIMIT 1";
```

Exemplo com delimitadores \"\"

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `nome` FROM usuario` WHERE  `usuario` = \"".$usuario."\" AND `senha` = \"".$senha."\" LIMIT 1";
```

Para se trabalhar com banco de dados você deve utilizar a classe [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php) nativa do php.

Para te ajudar a entender melhor vou te ajudar com um exemplo simples trabalhando com essa classe.

Conexão:

```
//Iniciamos a instância do objeto PDO
//e passamos no último parâmetro o tipo de caracteres
//que vamos trabalhar sendo tipo utf-8
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=seulocalhost;dbname=seubanco', 'seuuser', 'suasenha', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8"));

//Definimos para que o PDO lance exceções em casos de erro
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Instrução SQL para consulta simples:

```
// executa a instrução SQL
$consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT nome, senha FROM table_users");
```

Instrução SQL simples com passagem de parâmetros:

```
//prepara a instrução SQL utilizando o método "prepare()"
$consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT email, senha FROM table_users WHERE email=:email AND senha=:senha");


//Define os padrões de tipos de parâmetros em que a instrução deverá trabalhar
$consulta->bindValue(':email', 'sample@mail.com', PDO::PARAM_STR); //define para o mysql que este parâmetro deverá ser somente string
$consulta->bindValue(':senha', 'sample2017', PDO::PARAM_STR); //define para o mysql que este parâmetro deverá ser somente string
$consulta->execute(); //executa a query
```

Conta Registros

```
if($consulta->rowCount() >= 1){
    //code...
}
```

Percorrendo dados

```
foreach($consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $item) {
    echo $item->email;
}
```

Comment: Muito bom Rafael, Irei estudar suas dicas para meu aprendizado. Acabei resolvendo este caso de outra forma, usando o PDO e ajustando meu SQL conforme suas dicas acima. Grato

Comment: Estamos todos sempre aprendendo e buscando o melhor, fico feliz que tirou proveito disso tudo, abs!